# After apply this function, reload page

Tags: javascript

I need to reload the page after all these funtions are applied.

```
$('#r_btc').on('click', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    var b = jQuery.grep(ecomm._vCRT, function(f) {
        return f.s == pCRT._rIDS
    });
    if ('x' == b[0].t) ecomm._vCRT = jQuery.grep(ecomm._vCRT, function(f) {
        return f.s != pCRT._rIDS
    }),
    b[0].b = jQuery.grep(b[0].b, function(f) {
        return f != pCRT._rIDB
    }),
    0 < b[0].b.length ? (ecomm._vCRT.push({
        s: b[0].s,
        t: b[0].t,
        b: b[0].b,
        o: b[0].o,
        p: b[0].p
    }), ecomm.updBStat(pCRT._rIDB, pCRT._rIDS, 1, 0)) : ecomm._vCRT = jQuery.grep(ecomm._vCRT, function(f) {
        return f.s != pCRT._rIDS
        
    });
    else {
        jQuery.grep(b, function(f) {
            var g = jQuery.grep(f.b, function(h) {
                return h[0] != pCRT._rIDB[0]
            });
            b[0].b = '',
            b[0].b = g
        });
        ecomm._vCRT = jQuery.grep(ecomm._vCRT, function(f) {
            return f.s != pCRT._rIDS
        }),
        0 < b[0].b.length ? ecomm._vCRT.push({
            s: b[0].s,
            t: b[0].t,
            b: b[0].b
        }) : ecomm._vCRT = jQuery.grep(ecomm._vCRT, function(f) {
            return f.s != pCRT._rIDS
        }),
        ecomm.updBStat(pCRT._rIDB, pCRT._rIDS, 1, 0)
    }
    pCRT._rIDB = 0,
    pCRT._rIDS = 0,
    pCRT._rPVP = 0,
    pCRT.iCRT(),
    ecomm.chkSTCK(),
    app.cCookie('cart', JSON.stringify(ecomm._vCRT), 30),
    $('#confirmation-reveal').foundation('close')
    location.reload();
}),
```

This function is used to remove an element from the cart. So, I need to reload the page after an element is removed.

I don't know where I should insert the reload code here.

Comment: You already have `location.reload();` there, is that not reloading the page as expected?

Comment: Speaking as an experienced developer of ~8 years, I can say this code is hard to decipher. It's taken me ~5 minutes to refactor to a point where I can understand what it's even doing. Suggest refactoring this code to: a) use semicolons after each statement. I know JS allows leaving them out, but please, it really does help understanding. b) Don't use ternaries, especially in void context like you're doing. and c) Always use braced `if`/`else`. Also, keep in mind better questions have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as their code, not just a huge blob.

Comment: I suggest [using the debugger built into your browser](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) to set a breakpoint in that function. Then step through it line by line to see if it `throws` before reaching where you put the `location.reload()` line.